# How to save update from relationships model Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I want to save an update from One to Many relation model in Laravel 5.3, but I have this error.

> FatalThrowableError in HasOneOrMany.php line 221:
>   Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\wismasejahtera\app\Http\Controllers\JurnalController.php on line 129

Here is my Jurnals model:

```
public function djurnals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\DJurnals', 'jurnal_id');
}
```

And here is my Djurnals model:

```
public function jurnals()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Jurnals');
}

public function rekenings()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Rekenings');
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
$jurnal = Jurnals::find($id);
  $jurnal->no_jurnal = $request->no_jurnal;
  $jurnal->tgl_jurnal = $tglJurnalFix;
  $jurnal->keterangan = $request->keterangan;
  $jurnal->save();

  //ini Array
  $kode_rekening = $request->kode_rekening;

  for($i=0; $i<count($kode_rekening); $i++){
    $djurnal = Djurnals::where('jurnal_id', $id)->get();
    $djurnal->kode_rekening = $request->kode_rekening[$i];
    $djurnal->keterangan_rekening = $request->keterangan_rekening[$i];
    $djurnal->d_k = $request->d_k[$i];
    $djurnal->jumlah = $request->jumlah[$i];

    if($request->d_k[$i] == 'D'){
      $saldoRekKas = Rekenings::where('kode_rekening', 'like', '111%')
                                ->increment('saldo', $request->jumlah[$i]);
    }
    else{
      $saldoRekKas = Rekenings::where('kode_rekening', 'like', '111%')
                                ->decrement('saldo', $request->jumlah[$i]);
    }
    $jurnal->djurnals()->save($djurnal);
  }
  return Redirect::to('jurnal');
```

And the error is in this row in Controller:

```
$jurnal->djurnals()->save($djurnal);
```

When I use this way to save a new jurnal and djurnal, it works correctly. But, When I try to save an update, it show an error. How can I save this update data to database? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the `jurnal_id` to get the `Djurnals` model, you need to save it directly.

Replace

```
Djurnals::where('jurnal_id', $id)->get();
```

With

```
Djurnals::where('jurnal_id', $id)->first();
```

---

Replace

```
$jurnal->djurnals()->save($djurnal);
```

With

```
$djurnal->save();
```

`$jurnal->djurnals()->save($djurnal);` Should be used only when saving a newly created model.

Comment: ahh,, got it. But why it show me another error? method save doesn't exist

Comment: Updated my answer, replace `get()` with `first()` in you loop